# Time lag on change function

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery

I have a script to load a range of number. This range of number is only 200 lengths. However, it has a change function. When the start number is change, the the end number will try to find its range again.

The whole of code is working fine. However, it gives me a time lag (sometime get crash) on each change.

Can anyone help me to clean this code, please?

```js
function pad (str, max) 
    {
        str = str.toString();

        return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
    }

$("#game, #camp").on('change', function(){
    a = $("#game").val(), 
    b = $("#camp").val(),
    j = pad(a,2); 
    k = pad(b,2);
    c = j+k; 

    $("#serial").empty();


    for (var i = 1; i<=200; i++)
         {
             l = pad(i,3)
             $("#manual").append("<option value='"+(c+l)+"'>"+(c+l)+"</option>");
         }   


var $auto = $('#automatic'),
    $manual = $('#manual'),
    lastValue = +$manual.find('option').last().val();

    $manual.on('change', function () {


        var value = +$(this).val(),
        max = lastValue;

        //alert(max); 

        $auto.empty();

        for (var i = value; i < max; i++) 
            {
                $('<option>', 
                     {
                        value:i+1,  
                        text: i+1
                     }).appendTo($auto);
            }
    }).change()


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="game">
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
</select>

<select id="camp">
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="33">33</option>
    <option value="44">44</option>
    <option value="55">55</option>
    <option value="66">66</option>
    <option value="77">77</option>
</select>

<select id="manual"></select>
<select id="automatic"></select>
```

Comment: Please declare your [cross-posts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29886441/1157100).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Code hygiene

What is `$("#serial")`?  Did you mean `$("#manual").empty()` instead?

You are sloppy in localizing your variables.  `a`, `b`, `j`, `k`, `c`, `l`, `lastValue`, and `max` (the one in the `$manual.on('change')` handler) are all global.  All of them are horribly named.  Furthermore, I recommend eliminating unnecessary variables.

Take care to end your statements with a semicolon.  It's considered good practice even though the language doesn't require them.

#### Performance

There are two major problems.

The first issue is that it is much more efficient to append a giant string all at once than to manipulate the DOM an element at a time.

The second problem is that you are defining a change handler within a change handler.  That means the `#manual` element gets regenerated more and more frantically with each change in the first two columns.

```js
function pad(str, max) {
    str = str.toString();
    return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}

$('#manual').on('change', function() {
    var autoOptions = '';
    var lastValue = +$(this).find('option').last().val();
    for (var i = 1 + +$(this).val(); i <= lastValue; i++) {
        // Should i be padded to 7 digits?
        autoOptions += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
    }

    $('#automatic').html(autoOptions);
});

$("#game, #camp").on('change', function() {
    var gameCamp = pad($('#game').val(), 2) +
                   pad($('#camp').val(), 2);

    var manualOptions = '';
    for (var i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
        var iii = pad(i, 3);
        manualOptions += '<option value="' + gameCamp + iii + '">' + gameCamp + iii + '</option>';
    }
    $('#manual').html(manualOptions)
                .change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="game">
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
</select>

<select id="camp">
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="33">33</option>
    <option value="44">44</option>
    <option value="55">55</option>
    <option value="66">66</option>
    <option value="77">77</option>
</select>

<select id="manual"></select>
<select id="automatic"></select>
```

Comment: Yes, I forget to change the name `$("#serial")` (it is actually the real id of `#manual` in my code. Thank you very much, sir. You save my time in debugging this script. Once again, thank you so much for helping me out with this. (btw, I can't vote up, my rep is less than 15 reputation.)  Will vote it up as soon as I can. Once again, thank you!